# What does the flag notification color mean?

Tags: discussion, flags, design, moderator-tools

I recently noticed that the flag notification background color changed.

[image]

I was wondering why? What does it mean?
Or is it just a punctual change (as this block recently moved from the right of our picture, to the left)?

Comment: It's just consistency I think, let me bring up the meta post/comment.

Comment: There's no rule, it was just a change in design.

Comment: Congratulations, you're pregnant.